# Setting jQuery value into c:foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am basically trying to get values with an ajax request based on a specific id. I then would like to load the json List returned, and load it into a jstl foreach loop. This is my code for the ajax GET request:

```
$(this).on("click", ".edit_sighting", function(){
        var username = +$(".edit_sighting").val();
        $.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getSighting/" + username, function(sightings) {

        });
    });
```

My Button that gets pressed to load these values: So when this is instantiated, I want to load all the sightings that user has into a modal.

```
<button class="edit_sighting" value="${sighting.username}">Edit Sighting</button>
```

I want the returned 'sightings' to go into a c:foreach loop to show if the user has more than 1 sighting.

```
<c:forEach var="" items="${?}">

</c:forEach>
```

I dont know how to set the jQuery value returned into the 'var' section?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).on('click', '.edit_sighting', function() {
   $.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getSighting/' + $('.edit_sighting').val(), function(sightings) {
                                                                                           $('c\\:forEach').attr('var', sightings);
                                                                                        });
});
```

Also, why are you using `$(this)` as a selector when binding the click event?

Comment: Ok I will try, but what about the "items" attrribute

Comment: I don't know how your return data looks like and what it is you need in the `item` attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never used JSTL before. If you console.log(sightings), what do you get in your developer tools?